# How to prefill nested form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple nested form using the 'nested_form' gem.

It looks like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :username, :size => 25 %>

<%= f.fields_for :teams do |team_form| %>
  <%= team_form.label :team_name, 'Name of your team' %>

<% end %>
<%= f.submit :value =>'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to prefill the fields in my new-action. While it's easy to fill the username-field with `@user.username = "someone"` I have no idea how to access the first nested field "team_name" in the nested "team_form".

In the html the field looks like this:

```
<input id="user_teams_attributes_0_team_name" type="text" name="user[teams_attributes][0][team_name]">
```

Any ideas how to prefill this nested field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically `build` can be used for this in your controller *(as it doesn't cause a `save` on the `@user` object)*, appending new `Team` instances to the `:teams` collection on the `@user` object. In your action

```
@user = User.new
@user.teams = [ Team.build(...) ]
```

where `...` contains the default attributes for `@user.teams.first` that will be displayed in the nested form.

Comment: @Deefour Would @user.teams.build() achieve the same thing?